# FMX DrawBitmap gives error: "It is not possible to perform rendering. BeginScene was not invoked."

Tags: c++, firemonkey, c++builder

C++Builder 11.1.5, Firemonkey, Windows 64-bit

Copying some bitmaps and the error is:

> It is not possible to perform rendering.  BeginScene was not invoked.

Here is the code that is causing the error:

```
FinalBitmap->Canvas->BeginScene();
FinalBitmap->CopyFromBitmap(Cam1Bitmap, Cam1Rect, 0,0);
FinalBitmap->CopyFromBitmap(Cam2Bitmap, B2Rect, Cam1Bitmap->Width,0);

try {
    switch(Mode) {
        case NORMAL:
            FinalBitmap->Canvas->DrawBitmap(Temp2OBitmap, B2ORect, B1ORect, 1.0, false);
            break;

        case CALIBRATE:
           // Error occurs here.  Why????  
            FinalBitmap->Canvas->DrawBitmap(Temp2OBitmap, B2ORect, B1ORect, 0.5, false);
            break;
        }
    }
catch(...) {

    }

FinalBitmap->Canvas->EndScene();
```

I am calling `BeginScene` and `EndScene` properly. Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried enabling Debug DCUs in your project options and then step through the FMX source code with the debugger to find out what is actually failing? *WHICH* `TBitmap` object is raising the error? What is the value of `FinalBitmap->Canvas->BeginSceneCount` before executing this code? What you describe suggests that `BeginSceneCount` may be `-1` instead of `0` when this code runs, ie if `FinalBitmap->Canvas->EndScene()` was called too many times beforehand.

Comment: Remy,  I figured this one out but it took a while to lock it down.  I am capturing 2 images from 2 separate web cams.  If one of the web cams hasn't turned on in time, it returns a null bitmap image.  I just had to wait a few seconds to allow both cams to turn on properly then everything worked fine.